# Running Windows Phone 8 apps on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Do apps compiled for Windows Phone 8 run on Windows Phone 8.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes apps built for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 7 run on Windows Phone 8.1.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_8.1#App%20framework)